# Matlab C++ mex function that returns a diagonal matrix

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I need to create a Matlab mex function that takes an input of a matrix and outputs the matrix diagonal.
Ex.

input_matrix = ([1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9])

output_matrix = 
1 2 3 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 4 5 6 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 7 8 9

So far this is the code I have:

```
#include <matrix.h>
#include <mex.h>

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[]) {
        mxArray *a_in, *b_out;
        const mwSize *dims;
        double *a, *b; 
        int rows, cols;

        // Input array:
        a_in = mxDuplicateArray(prhs[0]);

        // Get dimensions of input array:
        dims = mxGetDimensions(prhs[0]);
        rows = (int) dims[0];
        cols = (int) dims[1];

        // Output array:
        b_out = plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(rows, rows*cols, mxREAL);
        
        // Access the contents of the input and output arrays:
        a = mxGetPr(a_in);
        b = mxGetPr(b_out);

        // Compute exdiag function of the input array:
        int n = rows * cols;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
             b[n*i+i] = a[i];
            
    }
}
```

It can only output the new matrix like this:
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 7 0 0

I do not know how to fix it. Can anyone help?

Comment: Think about what `n*i+i` does. Compute its value for each of your `i` in that loop, and notice how they go out of the range of the  output matrix which only has `rows*rows*cols` elements.

Comment: So how would you go about implementing the for loop? This is the second Mex function I have done so I have little knowledge on how it works fully.

Comment: Your problem is not specific to MEX-files, that part seems correct. You just need to change how you write the index into `b`. I think `rows*i + i/rows` might do the trick, not sure without trying it out. It might be easier to do two loops, one over the rows of `a` and one over the columns of `a`, then compute the location within `b` for each element in `a`.

Comment: This is how you would code it in Matlab `[m,n]=size(x);
y=zeros(m,m*n);
for i=1:m
    y(i,n*(i-1)+1:n*i)=x(i,:);
end` Do you know how I can translate that to my C++ Mex

Comment: The `n*(i-1)+1:n*i` part would be a second loop, iterating over each of the values in that range.